# How to get customer session data outside Magento

Tags: magento2, customer-session, data

I want to know if it is possible to get customer session data outside of magento2

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
$app = Mage::app('default'); 
Mage::app();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 require '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
    //$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('DemoApplication');
    //$bootstrap->run($app);
```

---

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
 $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
//mysql connection
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   echo $emial =    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();

}
```

Comment: I want that session in WordPress which is placed in magento root directory. I have created one file in theme front-page.php just want to know how it works. that page is working. could you please let  me know how to set path for bootstarp

Comment: I got that file but there were some error Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat::BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL php72compat.php on line 91

Comment: @Gagan: Regarding front-page.php : Yes, You can add this code inside <?php ?> PHP tag then check in browser like: http://yourdomain.com/front-page.php

Comment: Thanks @sangeeta its working fine but with some alterations. I will update that code on monday thanks for help

Comment: you can check your code now sangeeta thanks again